# How do I setup mongo db at last so i can use it with node Js on Windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to be able to use mongo db at last on my windows with node js. I get errors with my current installation when I type node app.js on command line.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// replace the uri string with your connection string.
const uri = "mongodb+srv://shahid:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-1q7ty.mongodb.net/test"

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
  if(err) {
       console.log('Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n',err);
       }
       console.log('Connected...');
       const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
       // perform actions on the collection object
       client.close();
    });
```

Comment: I improved formatting for you. Please add a missing error message by editing your question using the **edit** button.

Comment: Have you downloaded from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community ? Instructions are at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Comment: Did you replaced `<Password>` with your `password` in `uri`?

Comment: I have resloved the issue guys